# How to Hide Story Content from homepage in pligg powered site

Tags: pligg

Hide Story Content from Home page
indicator (#116) 10 hours ago storycontent Discuss 
Hi Everyone,
I want to hide storycontent from Home and category index but when visitor click on discussion then story-content should be there. How can I do that I tried but then story-content is hidden from everywhere.

Please help, thanks for assistance

Answer (score 0):

**Edit File:** `templates\bootstrap\link_summary.tpl`

**Find:**

```
{if $pagename eq "story"}
{* The nl2br modifier will convert line breaks to <br> tags. http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.nl2br.tpl*}
{$story_content|nl2br}
{else}
{* The truncate modifier will cut off content after X characters. http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.truncate *}
{$story_content|nl2br}
{/if}
```

**Replace with:**

```
{if $pagename eq "story"}
{* The nl2br modifier will convert line breaks to <br> tags. http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.nl2br.tpl*}
{$story_content|nl2br}
{/if}
```

Looks like there's a bug in Pligg here as the `else` branch is the same as the `if` branch. It seems they intended to use the `truncate` modifier from Smarty on the `else` branch to only show a summary on pages other than the story page.